# Search Functionality on a Django Site

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a search function to my website but I'm having some issues. It's currently telling me that "Search" is not defined, but I have the class in my views file. This is what I have thus far:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^player/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.player, name='player'),
    url(r'^season/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.season, name='season'),
    url(r'^seasons/$', views.seasons, name='seasons'),
    url(r'^search/$', Search.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Player, Season, PxS, Statistics

def home(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', {'seasons': seasons})

def player(request, pk):
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'webapp/player.html', {'player': player, 'seasons': player.season_set.order_by('sid'), 'statistics': player.statistics_set.all()})

def season(request, pk):
    season = get_object_or_404(Season, pk=pk) 
    return render(
        request, 
        'webapp/season.html',
        {'season': season, 'players': season.players.order_by('lastname')}
    )

def seasons(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/seasons.html', {'seasons': seasons})

class Search(ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    model = Player
    context_object_name = 'list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Search, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pobj = Player.objects.all()
        var_get_search = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
        var_get_order_by = self.request.GET.get('pid')

        if var_get_search is not None:
            pobj = pobj.filter(playername__icontains=var_get_search)

        if var_get_order_by is not None:
            pobj = pobj.order_by(var_get_order_by)

        return pobj
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. I'm kind of just piecing this stuff together little by little. Thanks!

Comment: Importing views is not enough; you need to import the `Search` class, like so: `from views import Search`

Comment: @JohnGordon I get an import error saying "No module named views" when I try that.

Comment: You should replace in urls.py Search.as_view() into views.Search.as_view()

Comment: Yeah @AleksandrKarasev is right. You should do it more like `from views import *` or explicitly like `from views import Search`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the urls.py

Give url(r'^search/$', views.Search.as_view(), name='search'),

instead of just Search.

Comment: I've adjusted my views url, but the form doesn't submit. It just reloads the page... 

`<form type="get" action="." style="margin: 0">
        <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
        <button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>`

Comment: i doubt your <form type="get" action="." style="margin: 0">
where action "." specifies to the same url which you are on now, and method="GET" hits a http GET to the server. 

Make sure you have processed the queryset in 'search.html' . When the submit button is pressed. It again request the same url(with query params if any given) . 

If you are on a different page and you want to hit the search view then
refactor the form a bit to
<form type="get" action="{% url 'search' %}" style="margin: 0">

Comment: To send 
    var_get_search = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
    var_get_order_by = self.request.GET.get('pid')
to server. 
you have to handle using client scrips ie, jquery or javascript.
make the search url and append the queryparams and request a http GET

Comment: So are you saying that this isn't possible without jQuery/JS?

Comment: If you need to query with different query params and data you have to make up that with front end scripts. in case of your code you need to write the script.